# How can I read a parquet file that uses the DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY encoding?

Tags: parquet

I am trying to read a parquet file that is quite bleeding edge, it uses v2 page format and encodes its columns with the `DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY` encoding. I was trying to read this file with the arrow/parquet C++ library but I just got `Parquet error: Not yet implemented: Unsupported encoding.` Next, I tried `pyarrow.parquet` and also this library just throws `OSError: Not yet implemented: Unsupported encoding.`

So, which open source library is able to read a file that is using this encoding?

Comment: Are you trying to read some AWS cost and usage reporting file? I'm having a similar issue with both pyarrow and fastparquet (cf. [fastparquet issue #493](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/493) ).

Comment: @JackoBongo: No, I just want to read parquet files in C++ in general. I ended up writing a whole parquet reading library all by myself :D. (Though, I don't think that would be a good answer to my question...)